# How many Dex saves does a creature make if it's affected by 2 separate explosions from the Melf's Minute Meteors spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

The description of the [Melf's Minute Meteors](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors) spell (EEPC, p. 20; XGtE, p. 161) states:

> You create six tiny meteors in your space. They float in the air and orbit you for the spell’s duration. When you cast the spell—and as a bonus action on each of your turns thereafter—you can expend one or two of the meteors, sending them streaking toward a point or points you choose within 120 feet of you. Once a meteor reaches its destination or impacts against a solid surface, the meteor explodes. Each creature within 5 feet of the point where the meteor explodes must make a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 2d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

How many saves does the creature(s) make if affected by 2 separate meteor explosions?

To better clarify. If a wizard sends 2 meteors towards a creature and causes an explosion on both sides of it, does that creature make 1 or 2 Dex Saves?

I've looked on reddit and Sage Advice for an official ruling.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least related): [When a creature is hit with more than one fireball simultaneously, do they take damage from all of them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128318/35259)

Comment: @jaycee it's not about me. Rules of this community say we ask for game & edition, not guess it, because the same question can be valid across many games and wrong guess = wrong answers.

Comment: If you be sure to add the [dnd-5e] tag to your questions (if your question is about D&D 5e, that is), in addition to whatever other tags you want to use (i.e. [saving-throw], etc), then hopefully you won't run afoul of the thing that Molot is describing. I mean, Melf's Minute Meteors is specific to D&D, but any game could have a Fireball, for example. And even with Melf's Minute Meteors, if that spell also appears in, say, D&D 3.5e, then the rules will be completely different, so an answer telling you about how it worked in 3.5e would be of no help to you. Tags help to avoid that problem :)

Comment: Understood. Will be sure to do in future posts.

Comment: @NathanS While I have to accept the ruling that it must be specified, I do not see how 3.X and 5E would be "completely different" in such a spell. In 3.X Dex Save would be Reflex Save, And of course the progression to more Meteors would be only Spell Level, rather then higher spell slot - in 3.X. The example you gave is not exactly the best one. | If you look for a good example for differences, just mention that nobody needs to prepare any spells, there is ritual casting and spells get more powerfull by using higher slots in 5E. Unlike DEX vs REF save, those are actually relevant differences.

Comment: @Christopher I don't have much to say in response other than you are wrong. You've pointed out a bunch of differences between 3.Xe and 5e, then you claim that they aren't "completely different", just because an expert can map between the differences? If someone posted an answer to this question talking about reflex saves and preparing the spell multiple times, that would clearly just confuse things and would not help this user with their 5e question at all.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the wording in the [Melf's Minute Meteors](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/melfs-minute-meteors)(Elemental Evil, 161) spell description, the creature has to make 2 different DEX Saves.

> Once a meteor reaches its destination or impacts against a solid surface, the meteor explodes. Each creature within 5 feet of the point where the meteor explodes must make a Dexterity saving throw.

It also makes sense from a logical standpoint. Rolling a DEX Save is basically trying to minimize the damage from an effect by moving or jumping out of the way. When 2 separate meteors streak towards you, they both need to be evaded.