# Can multiple artificers use Flash of Genius on the same skill check or saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

Can multiple Artificers use flash of Genius on 1 skill check?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 5):

#### Only one will apply - whichever has the highest Intelligence modifier.

The rules for combining game effects say (emphasis added):

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. **But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap**. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.
>
> — *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 252

Since this is two instances of the *same* ability, Flash of Genius, only one can apply to a given roll, and the one with the highest intelligence modifier is the "most potent".

#### There may be room for debate here.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128320/62294) goes into detail about *Instantaneous* duration spells, and argues that such spells are not affected by the "Combining Spell Effects" rule because of the phrase "while their durations overlap".

We see this same clause in the "Combining Game Effects" rule I quoted above. Flash of Genius is not given a "duration", but there is room to rule that it is "instantaneous" and may not be subject to the Combining Game Effects rule, which would allow multiple artificers to use Flash of Genius on the same roll.

Personally, I would rule that it doesn't work, per the first section of this answer.

Comment: I agree, even if the effect has an instantaneous "duration", it's still 2 effects with the same name acting simultaneously on the same thing.